# Issue with Phonegap in app browser

Tags: html, cordova

So I have been trying to load http://yahoo.com in a phonegap application. So when user opens the app, it automatically shows yahoo website as an app. Everything I do I'm still getting phonegap splash page and don't really know what else to do. Documentation on phonegap doesnt make sense, its confusing and in addition to that Cordova and Phonegap versions (in references) are wrong version.

Can you please put me in a right direction with a dummy guide to achieve this? I have done this last year but couldnt find my test app any more.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You want to load yahoo page inside your application and open the yahoo page as soon as your application is opened. Right?

To do this create a phonegap application. Assuming you know how to do it.

Add `inAppBrowser` plugin.

Then inside the device ready event,write this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script>

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady()
{
    window.open("http://www.yahoo.com",'_self',"location=no");
}

</script>
```